# 2gp tests are failing with 'No such column' when trying to access current package field dynamically from base package test code

Tags: managed-package, failing-tests, 2gp

We have our 2gp package B which depends from package A.
We've also added new custom field into package B but for custom object from package A, like extending base package object with our own customization.

The troubles happen when we start writing tests for package B.
In test class we create a list of fields to query for (including standard fields, fields from package A, and new field from package B).
Then we call some global test utils method from package A (inside which it tries to query or create new sobject).
And we are getting 'No such column' error regarding that new field introduced in package B every time when creating package version (locally tests have passed).

We've tried also to execute query explicitly right in package B test class code (i.e. before calling global test utils from package A) and such query works as well.
But when it just crosses the boundary and enters package A's test util method, it stops seeing that new field from package B (i.e. just one line down the code, it's still same user, same profile, same test).

Does anyone have some ideas/suggestions why can't we access dynamically field of child package from test code of parent base package?

P.S. After commenting failing piece of tests and creating package version, we've verified that everything works fine from business logic perspective, i.e. there is no such problem in real world and it's just test problem on package version creation.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPD
Below is a simple skeleton to represent a problem in the code, assuming MyPackageA is a base 2gp package (with namespace A), and MyPackageB is an extension/child package (namespace B) with dependency from A.

```
@IsTest
class MyPackageB_Test {

    @isTest
    static void basicTestMethod_fromPackageB() {
        
        // this one works perfectly fine and continue execution to next line
        List<A__MyObject__c> records = [ SELECT Id, Name, A__SomeField__c, B__NewField__c FROM A__MyObject__c ];
        
        // this is where the failure happens here - No such column 'B__NewField__c'
        // but it fails only when creating new package version
        List<A__MyObject__c> recordsAgain = 
A.DataAccessService.query('SELECT Id, Name, A__SomeField__c, B__NewField__c FROM A__MyObject__c');
        
        
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show some code of what's failing? I think I know what might be going on, but to confirm, I'd need to see some code.

Comment: @sfdcfox Updated with test code example.